# Role of isopropanol in plasmid isolation

Tags: molecular-biology

In plasmid isolation, isopropanol is used to renature only the plasmid macromolecules after we precipitate all macromolecules(DNA, RNA, plasmids) using sodium acetate solution. How does it do that? How does it not renature every other macromolecule?

Answer (score 4):

In a standard DNA preparatory procedure, isopropanol is used to precipitate the DNA. Nucleic acids are insoluble in alcohols, and bulk or stick together. This sticking together can be further enhanced by increasing the ionic strength such as through addition of sodium acetate.

alcohols in fact don't really denature the DNA.